# Drupal 6 (basic): Change Login Page

Tags: theming, users

I want to change default login page to html login page because I like the theme (bought theme but still in html). After googling:
1. I use bluemarine theme,  as a start i modify page.tpl.php and replace all html parts
2. Place assets folder in the "themes/bluemarine" folder and replace "assets/.." to "themes/bluemarine/assets/..", until this step login page has been changed flawlessly

But, I don't know how to routing login page to normal destination. In the html code in point 1, I changed this:

```
"<form class="login-form" action="index.html" method="post">
```

to this one:

```
<form class="login-form" action="?q=dashboard" method="post">
```

Because I have a custom module called dashboard.

Please help me, thanks before...

Comment: Drupal 6 is no longer supported **[Drupal 6 end-of-life announcement](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)** I hope you're upgrading to 7 or 8 soon.

Comment: Thanks, I know that and we're upgrading our modules to D8 too.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be replacing Drupal form code with static HTML code for various reasons. You can redirect users to specific URLs by using Rules or actions/triggers:

https://www.drupal.org/node/683696

Comment: Any good ways how to convert static html login page to drupal form code?

Comment: BTW, now I couldn't login to admin area.

Comment: Instead of altering the form code, you should theme around the elements that you need to change. The Form API is doing a lot for you, including validation and submission (registering and logging in the user). You can test this by simply going to /user or using the user login block provided by Drupal to test that logins actually work before making any modifications. Do that first, and ensure the Action/Trigger is properly redirecting to 'dashboard' on login.